# Conditional Probabilities Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-distribution

If I let ${X(t); t>=0}$ be  a Poisson process having rate parameter $\lambda = 2$.  I'm supposed to determine the probability:

Pr{${X(1)>=2 | X(1) >=1}$}

My solution:
I looked at this as satisfying the memoryless property Pr{${X>s+t|X>t}$}=P{${X>s}$}

Thus the answer I get is Pr{${X(1)>1}$}=$e^-2$

But the book gives an answer of $(1-3e^-2) \over (1-e^-2)$

Anyone know where I went wrong/what I am missing?

Comment: The Poisson is not memoryless. The **exponential** (and the geometric) are memoryless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P\left(X\geq2\mid X\geq1\right)=\frac{P\left(X\geq2\wedge X\geq1\right)}{P\left(X\geq1\right)}=\frac{P\left(X\geq2\right)}{P\left(X\geq1\right)}=\frac{1-3e^{-2}}{1-e^{-2}}$$

[Memoryless property](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~guffin/teaching/fall10/lectures/lecture-23.pdf) is dealing with $T_1$ denoting the first time an event occurs:
$$P(T_1>s+t\mid T_1>s)=P(T_1>t)$$